# MasterPage Edit Issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, editing-menu

I'm new in Sharepoint. I created a custom masterpage.

When I want to add a web part to the page, I select the edit page button but the insert section in the ribbon doesn't appear.

I tried to do it in the Sharepoint Designer also but it doesn't make any change in the site.

In code it seems the webpart code is added but when I preview the page the added webpart doesn't appear.

Could you help me please?

Comment: do you mean the edit button for your webpage not masterpage? you cant add any webpart to the webpage because you cant see the edit button on the top breadcrum menu?

Comment: yes that is exactly true

Comment: @aliSharepoint I edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: ok thats alot better! ill reopen it for you!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons for this to happen.

The first is, the master page that you were editing was not the active, master page.

The second, in case you edited a html master page, it could happen, that the link between the aspx and html file was broken, so the changes did not persist.

Answer (score 0):

Since you create custom master page ..can you also please insure ContentPlaceHolder with ID "PlaceHolderMain" is placed in masterpage and its visible as shown below

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server" />
```